# Inplace argument in set_index for a dataframe is not supported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the problem that I am working on a dataframe and I want to set the argument `inplace = True` at the `set_index`.

My code looks like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('../some/data.csv')

df2 = df[df['DIVISION'] == '1']

df2.set_index('NAME', inplace=True)
print(df2.columns)
```

When hovering over it, `inplace=True` is underlined in red and the following message appears:

> Keyword arguments within subscripts are not supported.

When I click on the definition of `set_index` I see the following code snippet:

```py
def set_index(
        self,
        keys,
        drop: bool = True,
        append: bool = False,
        inplace: bool = False,
        verify_integrity: bool = False,
    )
```

Is something deprecated here or am I using too new a version? 
Currently I use the Pandas version **1.4.3** and the Python version **3.10.5**.

Everything looks fine to me, there is actually no error here.

Comment: Have you tried with other dummy data?...For me logic looks absolutly fine...Try once again on diffrent IDE..

Comment: For some reason, restarting VS Code and typing the code again fixed the error.  Although I had already tested this out it seems to work today. Think I can close the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, restarting VS Code and typing the code again fixed the error. Although I had already tested this out it seems to work today. Think I can close the question here.